# What is the value for $\tan^{-1}(1)+\tan^{-1}(2)$?

Tags: trigonometry

From the formula $$\tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1}(y) = \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$$
we get that $\tan^{-1}(1)+\tan^{-1}(2)$ should be $\tan^{-1}(-3)$.

But if you calculate the value $\tan^{-1}(1)+\tan^{-1}(2)$ directly, you get a positive value that is not equal to $\tan^{-1}(-3)$.

Sorry for the silly question!

Answer (score 1):

The quoted formula cannot be right, as your argument clearly shows. Let $\theta$ be our sum. A close relative of the quoted formula, namely
$$\tan(s+t)=\frac{\tan s+\tan t}{1-\tan s\tan t},$$
 **is** right whenever $\tan s$ and $\tan t$ are defined, and the denominator is non-zero. Using it  we find that $\tan(\theta)=-3$.

Note now that $\arctan(-3)$ is the number between $-\pi/2$ and $0$ whose tangent is $-3$. But our sum $\theta$ is between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$. To find the angle between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$ whose tangent is $-3$, add $\pi$. We find that $\theta=\pi+\arctan(-3)$, or if you prefer, $\pi-\arctan(3)$.

Answer (score 0):

See http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2009-02.pdf for a formula relating the function atan.

Also interesting http://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/pi-machin/